# How to can make a scatter plot of xy column but based on the value of 'id' column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this.

```
 ID        X     Y CLASS  
  A      123   456     0 
  A      789   121     1 
  A      456   333     1
  B      111   123     1   
  B      156   123     1
  C      167   189     1
  C      567   789     1
```

I want to group the same values for 'id' and make different scatter plots based on the xy axis in the same figure.
Right now, I am using

```
groups = df.groupby('id')
```

This makes separate groups and manually plotting for different id's but I'd like to do plot all the scatters in a single image and separate them based on the class. Sorry if the question is too 'noob'. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same results in which column? Y?

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you different scatterplots for different IDs in the same image. I think this is what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
g=sns.FacetGrid(df, row='ID')
g=g.map(plt.scatter, x='Y', y='Y')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can have one scatterplot with different point-colors for each ID with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(df['X'], df['Y'], hue = df['ID'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying do the first one but, it doesn't seem to work. I get a output like [link](https://imgur.com/a/AaD89CM) with only one point at the center coordinate. \imgur link/.

Comment: Can you please check your column names, if they much 'X' and 'Y' (no spaces, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the same plot, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name, group in df.groupby('ID'):
    plt.scatter(group.X, group.Y, label=name)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have worded in wrong. I want different plots on the same plane. Because the different id's may share coordinates.